# Вывести массив с данными в select->option->value

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как поставить массив arr в значение value (select->option->value).
И пользователю выводить только текст который содержит массив array() проще говоря, array показывает текст между тэгами 
 а значение value массив arr

**Подскажите что нужно поправить в коде чтобы было так:**

```
<select >
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Замечание</option>
    <option value="2">согласовано</option>
    <option value="3">не согласовано</option>
</select>
```

**на данный момент получается только так:**

```
<select >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Замечание">Замечание</option>
    <option value="согласовано">согласовано</option>
    <option value="не согласовано">не согласовано</option>
</select>
```

**Код**

```
var array = [" ", "Замечание", "согласовано", "не согласовано"];
//var arr=["0", "1", "2", "3"]; как разместить данный массив в value option
var select;
select=document.createElement('select');
select.name=this.dataset.name;
select.dataset.id=this.dataset.id;

select.type='text';
var val=this.innerHTML;
select.value=this.innerHTML;
this.dataset.old=this.innerHTML;
this.innerHTML='';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);

    option.text = array[i];

    select.appendChild(option);
}
select=this.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: заменить `option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);` на `option.setAttribute("value", i);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте массив из объектов, содержащих name и value.

```js
var array = [
  {name:" ", value:0},
  {name:"Замечание", value:1},
  {name:"согласовано", value:2},
  {name:"не согласовано", value:3333}
];

var select;
select=document.createElement('select');
select.name=this.dataset.name;
select.dataset.id=this.dataset.id;

select.type='text';
var val=this.innerHTML;
select.value=this.innerHTML;
this.dataset.old=this.innerHTML;
this.innerHTML='';
for (var i in array) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", array[i].value);

    option.text = array[i].name;

    select.appendChild(option);
}
select=this.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: код работает как нужно, подскажите а как быть в следующей ситуации. У меня select динамический, и когда я нажимаю на ячейку в таблице то появляется select со значениями (Замечание) и так далее, как только теряется фокус созданного объекта добавляется значение value в ячейку (тут все правильно). Но в бд добавляется значение. Я просто думал что останется текст между тэгами <option></option> а вышло по другому.

Comment: @Элиот Судя по всему, этот комментарий тянет на еще один вопрос.

Comment: я думал  вкратце сможете объяснить)

Comment: @Элиот Я даже толком не смог понять вопрос. Если сейчас правильно понял, то на серверной стороне нужно создать таблицу со значениями и добавлять ID, а при выборке данных связывать таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [" ", "Замечание", "согласовано", "не согласовано"];
var select = document.createElement("select");
array.forEach(function(v,k){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = k;
    option.innerHTML = v;
    select.appendChild(option);
});
```

Comment: Зря минусанули, вдруг товарищу захочется не такие плоские `value`?

Comment: @vp_arth тогда логичнее создать объект из пар - ключей и значений, а тут как то костыльно получается.

Comment: @SLy_huh я сделал так, как поставлен был вопрос. быть может второй массив берётся со стороны и ему нужно именно так. но так как он принял вариант пар, я отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: Я очень рад, но зачем делать массив в массиве, если для этого есть объект? `xzibit`?

Comment: @SLy_huh смысл если значений всего 2? как по мне это лишнее приписывать ключи в виде строк когда известно что больше 2 значений там не будет

Comment: Есть мнение, что запись вида `{1: 'Замечание, 2: 'Согласовано''}` короче и удобнее, чем `[['Замечание', 1], ['Согласовано', 2]]`. Ровно как и пользование ей.

Comment: @SLy_huh тогда есть смысл привести его вообще в изначальное состояние, пусть будет как второй вариант.